# Replacing elements in list of lists PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I've developed a predicate which replaces the value of the index `Index` of a list `List` with `Value` and creates a new updated list `NewList`.

```
%replace(List,Index,Value,NewList)

replace([_|T], 0, X, [X|T]).
replace([H|T], I, X, [H|R]):-
        I > -1, 
        NI is I-1,
        replace(T, NI, X, R), !.
replace(L, _, _, L).
```

The predicate works fine on regular lists, but I want to make it work on a list of lists and I am kind of stuck on a little step.

```
subs([]).
subs([Head|Tail], Index) :-
        replace((Head), Index, 'r', Board2),
        printRow(Board2),
        subs(Tail).
```

**Original List:**

```
[ [  0 ,  1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ] ,
  [  5 ,  6 ,  7 ,  8 ,  9 ] ,
  [ 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 ] ,  
  [ 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 ] ,  
  [ 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 23 ]
]
```

**Output:**

```
[ [  0 , r ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ] ,  
  [  5 , r ,  7 ,  8 ,  9 ] ,  
  [ 10 , r , 12 , 13 , 14 ] ,  
  [ 15 , r , 17 , 18 , 19 ] ,  
  [ 20 , r , 22 , 23 , 23 ]
]
```

It is noticeable why this happens, since it replaces the value with `Index = 1` on each sublist. 
In order to fix it, I thought about implementing a counter. By incrementing the index by 5 each iteration (size of each sub list), the predicate should now output the following (desired) list:

**Desired Output:**

```
[ [  0 ,  r ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 ] ,
  [  5 ,  6 ,  7 ,  8 ,  9 ] ,
  [ 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 ] ,  
  [ 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 ] ,
  [ 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 23 ]
]
```

And the issue lies on how to implement that very counter. The code should look like the following but there's something I'm missing out on:

```
subs([]).
subs([Head|Tail], Index) :-
        replace((Head), Index, 'r', Board2),
        printRow(Board2),
        Index is Index + 5
        subs(Tail, Index).
```

**Output:** `subs(<Original List>, 7).`

```
0  1  2  3  4
```

Can anyone give me some help on how to implement it?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Exactly what do you want `subs` to do on a list of lists? You have two clauses for `subs` right now. One takes one argument (`subs([]).`) and the other takes two (`subs([Head|Tail], Index) :-...`). Please explain exactly what `subs(L, Index)` means when `L` is a list of lists.

Comment: It is supposed to replace the element of Index = 'Index' of the list of lists. Although it replaces on every sublist of the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem statement is a bit unclear.

From your examples, it would appear that what you want to treat a list-of-lists as essentially a 2-D array, and replace a single cell within that array. If so, this is one way (probably non-optimal) to do that:

```
%
% replace a single cell in a list-of-lists
% - the source list-of-lists is L
% - The cell to be replaced is indicated with a row offset (X)
%   and a column offset within the row (Y)
% - The replacement value is Z
% - the transformed list-of-lists (result) is R
%
replace( L , X , Y , Z , R ) :-
  append(RowPfx,[Row|RowSfx],L),     % decompose the list-of-lists into a prefix, a list and a suffix
  length(RowPfx,X) ,                 % check the prefix length: do we have the desired list?
  append(ColPfx,[_|ColSfx],Row) ,    % decompose that row into a prefix, a column and a suffix
  length(ColPfx,Y) ,                 % check the prefix length: do we have the desired column?
  append(ColPfx,[Z|ColSfx],RowNew) , % if so, replace the column with its new value
  append(RowPfx,[RowNew|RowSfx],R)   % and assemble the transformed list-of-lists
  .
```

Another way (probably more optimal):

```
replace( [L|Ls] , 0 , Y , Z , [R|Ls] ) :- % once we find the desired row,
  replace_column(L,Y,Z,R)                 % - we replace specified column, and we're done.
  .                                       %
replace( [L|Ls] , X , Y , Z , [L|Rs] ) :- % if we haven't found the desired row yet
  X > 0 ,                                 % - and the row offset is positive,
  X1 is X-1 ,                             % - we decrement the row offset
  replace( Ls , X1 , Y , Z , Rs )         % - and recurse down
  .                                       %

replace_column( [_|Cs] , 0 , Z , [Z|Cs] ) .  % once we find the specified offset, just make the substitution and finish up.
replace_column( [C|Cs] , Y , Z , [C|Rs] ) :- % otherwise,
  Y > 0 ,                                    % - assuming that the column offset is positive,
  Y1 is Y-1 ,                                % - we decrement it
  replace_column( Cs , Y1 , Z , Rs )         % - and recurse down.
  .                                          %
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the possible mislead in my statement, but its been almost 8h of hardcore Prolog'ing. And yes, that is exacly what I'm looking for.
The predicate I built (replace) works on lists, but not on 2d ones. With subs I was trying to analyze each sub list individually, and increment the index after each iteration so that it wouldn't go back to 0. Was I far too off?

Later on I will edit my question so that more people can understand what I was trying to say.