# Replace element in list of list that contains list in Prolog

Tags: list, matrix, replace, prolog, element

I have done some search and tried many appends that I saw in some questions of stackoverflow, but I can't solve my problem...

It's almost that problem, but I have one more list inside it:

[Replacing elements in list of lists PROLOG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719774/replacing-elements-in-list-of-lists-prolog)

**My Matrix:**

```
[
    [[-1], [-1], [-1], [4], [-1], [-1], [-1]],
    [[-1], [0], [1], [0], [2], [-1]],
    [[3], [4], [3], [1], [1], [2], [3]],
    [[1], [5], [4], [2], [4], [3]],
    [[2], [3], [4], [0], [4], [4], [1]],
    [[2], [3], [1], [3], [0], [4]],
    [[0], [1], [0], [3], [2], [1], [0]],
    [[-1], [2], [2], [5], [0], [-1]],
    [[-1], [-1], [-1], [4], [-1], [-1], [-1]]
]
```

I need a method to replace one list containing numbers with a new list and returning the all matrix with the value replaced.
The method replace receives the row number and the column (position) number and the new value for the position.

Do anyone have an idea how can to make this?

**EDIT:**

The internal lists contain 1-5 elements. The inputs are: Matrix, Row, Cell, NewValue. And the main goal is to return a new Matrix with the newValue on the Cell of the Row.

**Example:**

I want to set my row nº1 and cell nº 4 to the value: [1,2,3].

So the output matrix will be:

```
[
    [[-1], [-1], [-1], [1,2,3], [-1], [-1], [-1]],
    [[-1], [0], [1], [0], [2], [-1]],
    [[3], [4], [3], [1], [1], [2], [3]],
    [[1], [5], [4], [2], [4], [3]],
    [[2], [3], [4], [0], [4], [4], [1]],
    [[2], [3], [1], [3], [0], [4]],
    [[0], [1], [0], [3], [2], [1], [0]],
    [[-1], [2], [2], [5], [0], [-1]],
    [[-1], [-1], [-1], [4], [-1], [-1], [-1]]
]
```

So the method replaces the list [4] with the list [1,2,3].

Comment: I edited the initial post. I'm sorry for didn't post an example

Comment: it doesn't matter what the list's element is. it can be an atom, a list, a compound term. an element is an element. so, this is exact duplicate of the one you linked. do show us the code you tried. it should've worked as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI-Prolog has a [builtin](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/4) that could help:

```
test :- I=[ [[-1], [-1], [-1], [4], [-1], [-1], [-1]],
        [[-1], [0], [1], [0], [2], [-1]],
        [[3], [4], [3], [1], [1], [2], [3]],
        [[1], [5], [4], [2], [4], [3]],
        [[2], [3], [4], [0], [4], [4], [1]],
        [[2], [3], [1], [3], [0], [4]],
        [[0], [1], [0], [3], [2], [1], [0]],
        [[-1], [2], [2], [5], [0], [-1]],
        [[-1], [-1], [-1], [4], [-1], [-1], [-1]]
    ],
    replace_row_col(I,1,4,[1,2,3],Upd),
    maplist(writeln,Upd).

replace_nth(N,I,V,O) :-
    nth1(N,I,_,T),
    nth1(N,O,V,T).

replace_row_col(M,Row,Col,Cell,N) :-
    nth1(Row,M,Old),
    replace_nth(Col,Old,Cell,Upd),
    replace_nth(Row,M,Upd,N).
```

yields

```
?- test.
[[-1],[-1],[-1],[1,2,3],[-1],[-1],[-1]]
[[-1],[0],[1],[0],[2],[-1]]
[[3],[4],[3],[1],[1],[2],[3]]
[[1],[5],[4],[2],[4],[3]]
[[2],[3],[4],[0],[4],[4],[1]]
[[2],[3],[1],[3],[0],[4]]
[[0],[1],[0],[3],[2],[1],[0]]
[[-1],[2],[2],[5],[0],[-1]]
[[-1],[-1],[-1],[4],[-1],[-1],[-1]]
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! Nice and simple approach :)